# StackOverflowException with JetBrains dotCover in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, dotcover

I use TeamCity to support continuous integration of a project.

Currently, when I run .NET Code Coverage: JetBrains dotCover for a specific project then the dotCover crashes with StackOverflowException.

Also, the unit test 'TestSomething' is correct and always runs successfully.

Here are the error logs snapshot from the build:

```
[MyAssembly.dll] MyAssembly.MyTester.TestSomething (12s)
[18:28:37][MyAssembly.MyTester.TestSomething] 
[18:28:37][MyAssembly.MyTester.TestSomething] Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
[18:28:38][MyAssembly.MyTester.TestSomething] [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished [12/22/2015 6:28:38 PM]
[18:28:38][MyAssembly.MyTester.TestSomething] [JetBrains dotCover] Analysed application exited with code '-1073741571'
[18:28:38][MyAssembly.MyTester.TestSomething] [JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished but no snapshots were created. 
[18:28:39][MyAssembly.MyTester.TestSomething] ##teamcity[importData type='dotNetCoverage' tool='dotcover' file='C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\coverage_dotcover33181917853826188801.data']
[18:28:37][Step 3/10] 
[18:28:37][Step 3/10] Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

I really cannot understand why this happens.

Any help from experts?

Comment: Are you mentioning dotCover because it's specific to dotCover? Would it also crashed if you switched dotCover off (and hence ran the tests with plain NUnit - or whatever test system you use)?

Comment: When I run the unit tests with NUnit (either NUnit console or NUnit UI) there is no problem. Also, when I run these from Resharper there is no problem. I think that has something to do with dotCover. I have tried to run the code coverage from dotCover locally in my machine and I am facing another problem now. dotCover returns unsuccessfully with '-100' exit code after some time of execution. Many unit tests pass but at some point fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in JetBrains dotCover.

Comment: Do you have any pointers to a workaround? Or a fix I should apply?

Comment: I'm getting this error in TeamCity 10.0.3, which is the latest version as of today.

Comment: @DavidKeaveny I could confirm it happens with our TC 10.0.3 as well 1-3 times a day.

Comment: There is the related bug reported in TeamCity issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44103. Please watch the ticket to get updates.

Comment: Still not solved, so that's not much use.